# Having trouble rewriting code to list comprehension for image rotation in python

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, list-comprehension

So after not finding my problem here on stackoverflow, which is how to rewrite a for-loop to a list comprehension, where values are inserted I have to ask now if it possible to rewrite this code:

```
rotate = np.zeros((w,h,c), np.uint8) # create an empty image filled with zeros turned 90°

for y in xrange(h):
    for x in xrange(w):
        rotate[x][y] = img[y][x]
```

into list comprehension? I thought something like this would work, but it didn't:

```
rotate[x][y] = img[y][x] for y in range(h) for x in range(w)
```

after that I just played around with various combinations of adding indexes and brackets and I always got some syntax errors. Just for the record, I know that there are functions for rotation of images in opencv and in numpy, I'm just interested in rewriting the  for-loop to list-comprehension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
rotate = np.array([[img[y][x] for y in xrange(h)] for x in xrange(w)])
```

Comment: it works, but why do you have to use np.array()? Is there a way without that?

Comment: @dima list comprehensions returns lists, so you'll have to convert that list into a numpy array.

Comment: If you don't want a numpy array, you can just assign the resulting list directly to `rotate`.

Comment: no, I checked now that cv2.imraed() returns a numpy array and so I need it. Thank you, very much.